# Add the size value to its previous value in Multithreading program

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have started working on a project in which I need to sum the `size` of `beAttributes` in every call with its previous `size`.

Below is my code-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int noOfThreads = 2;

    //create thread pool with given size 
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);


    for (int i = 0, i< noOfThreads; i++) {
        service.submit(new ThreadTask());
    }

    // wait for termination        
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);

    System.out.println(ThreadTask.count_size);
}

class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

    public static int count_size = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(time < 10 minutes) {
            try {

            ...

            List<BEAttribute<?>> beAttributes = beClient.getBEAttributes(columnsList);

            // Now I need to sum the beAttributes.size in every call

                final int size = beAttributes.size;
                count_size = count_size + size;
            ...

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Suppose in the while loop, for the first call to `getBEAttributes`method, I got `beAttributes.size` as `20`. Then I should store that `20 number` in some static integer. And now in other call to `getBEAttributes` method, I got `beAttributes.size` as `40`, then I should add this `40` to previous `20`. So now that static integer will become 60. And keep on doing this process until the program is finished. And print the same static integer from the main thread.

The way I am doing currently is thread safe or not? I guess there is a problem with the way I am doing increment. If yes, can anyobody help me with the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really thread safe as you have several threads accessing the same variable, `count_size`. My suggestion (easy fix) is to use a [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of an int. They have the atomic (i.e. mutual exclusion is guaranteed) methods `getAndAdd(int size)` and `addAndGet(int size)` which you can use to add to it. To make it thread-safe you also need to make the variable volatile - this ensures no local caching is done. For instance:

```
public static volatile AtomicInteger countSize = new AtomicInteger();

//...
while() {
    //...
    countSize.getAndAdd(beAttributes.size);
    //...
}
```

To get the int value: `ThreadTask.countSize.get()`.

You could also make your own methods with your own lock to add to the variable, for instance:

```
private static volatile int countSize = 0;
private static Object lock = new Object();


private static void addToSize(int i) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        countSize+=i;
    }
}
public static int getCount() {
    synchronized(lock) { //it is good practice to synch getters too - although not entirely necessary with ints.
        return countSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pesci for the help. Just to make sure, do I need to make that countSize as volatile?

Comment: Yeah however you do it that has to be done, for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_Java

Answer (score 0):

the following operation is not atomic：

```
count_size = count_size + size;
```

try bellow:

```
public static   AtomicInteger countSize = new AtomicInteger()
```

and

```
countSize.getAndAdd(beAttributes.size);
```